# How to use chart's default timeframe in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I wonder how we can use a default timeframe based on the chart's timeframe selected by the user.  So, instead of using input.timeframe('', title='High/Low Lines'), the script works base on the current chart's timeframe? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `timeframe.period`